# has_many binding on wrong parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many

I have `show.html.erb`:

```
<h3>Rooms (<%= @building.rooms.count %>)</h3>
<%= render @rooms %>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
OCIError: ORA-00904: "ROOMS"."BUILDING_ID": invalid identifier: \
SELECT "ROOMS".* FROM "ROOMS" WHERE "ROOMS"."BUILDING_ID" = :a1`
```

Here are models:

```
class Building < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rooms
end

class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building
end
```

Here's `buildings_controller.rb`:

```
class BuildingsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @building = Building.find(params[:id])
    @rooms = @building.rooms.all
  end
```

The `building` model has attributes:

```
ID, NAME, CREATED_AT, UPDATED_AT, CODE
```

The `room` model has attributes:

```
ID, NAME, CREATED_AT, UPDATED_AT, BUILDING_CODE, NUMBER
```

Comment: What Database are you using? Oracle? MySQL? PostgreSQL?

Comment: so what should it be doing?

Comment: Displaying all rooms that belong to a specific building where Building.code = Room.building_code

Comment: Instead of using BUILDING.ID and ROOM.BUILDING_ID, I'd Like to use BUILDING.CODE and ROOM.BUILDING_CODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should define an explicit [foreign_key](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-foreign-key) on `Room`

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building, foreign_key: :code
end
```

that way you tell active record to use building.code for the lookup.

Of course you will also need the proper migration to define `room.building_code`

eg

```
def change
  add_column :rooms, :building_code, :integer # or :string
  add_index :rooms, :building_code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `Room` model, change the association to become like this:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :building, primary_key: 'code'
end
```

This will tell rails that the association's primary key is `code` instead of the default `id`.